# Django view and serializer of manyToMany using through

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have the following structure:
Each account has list of stores, and each store has list of lines.

**models:**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    lines = models.ManyToManyField('Line', through='AccountLine', related_name='accounts')


class Store(models.Model):       
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ExtendedData(models.Model):
    x1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    x2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('store', 'name')


class AccountLine(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    line = models.ForeignKey('Line', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    extended_data = models.ForeignKey('ExtendedData', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('line', 'account')
```

I need to create a list view of account's stores, and for each stores the list of connected lines, including the 'through' extra fields 'is_active' , like the following json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,        -- Store id
    "type": "store_type_1", --store type
    "name": "Store1",      --store name
    "lines": [
      {
        "id": 0,     -- AccountLine id--need for update
        "name": "Line1",-- Line name
        "extended_data": {
          "x1": true,
          "x2": 0
        },
        "is_active": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**serializer:**
I'm not sure they are correct but that what I got so far:

```
class ExtendedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedData
        fields = ('x1', 'x2')


class AccountLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='line.name')
    extended_data = ExtendedDataSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AccountLine
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'is_active', 'extended_data')


class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='store.id')
    type = serializers.CharField(source='store.type')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='store.name')
    questions = TenantHasQuestionSerializer(many=True, source='line_set')
    
    class Meta:
        model = AccountLine
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'name', 'questions')
```

Comment: Can you share the view, queryset, and serializer you have so far?

Comment: @BrianDestura I added the serializer, but actually I don't know how to do the view and queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you would have to go through you models using relationship, starting with a few changes:

models.py

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    # removed related name
    lines = models.ManyToManyField('Line', through='AccountLine')
...
class AccountLine(models.Model):
    # Add related name to the through table.
    line = models.ForeignKey(
        'Line', 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
        related_name='accounts'
    )
    ...
```

build serializers for your models, with the help of [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```py
class ExtendedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ExtendedData
        fields = ['x1', 'x2']

class AccountLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extended_data = ExtendedDataSerializer()
    name = serializers.CharField(source='line.name')

    class Meta:
        model = models.AccountLine
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'extended_data', 'is_active']

class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lines = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ['id', 'type', 'name', 'lines']

    def get_lines(self, instance):
        account_lines = []
        lines = instance.line_set.all()
        for line in lines:
            account_line = line.accounts.all()[0]
            account_lines.append(AccountLineSerializer(account_line).data)

        return account_lines
```

And, a simple generic [`ListAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview):

```py
class StoreListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoreSerializer
```